# removing IntelliJ project from version control

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

Is there a way to remove version control from an IntelliJ project? I could go through the directory structure and remove all the .svn files on the command line, but I just wonder if there's a "proper" or easier way to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @enkor, how you look at the 'ask' dates, mine pre-dates by couple of years, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you better phrase your question...

IntellJ is an IDE. If you're using it to download source code from a Subversion repository, try the export command instead of checkout. That will download all the source files without the `.svn` directories. Of course, you'll be unable to check in any of your changes back into the Subversion repository.

Open the repository browser, then right click on the directory instead of pressing the Checkout button on the bottom. You'll see the *export* menu item. Select that, and that will checkout the source from the Subversion repository without the `.svn` folders. Of course, you won't be able to check anything back in.

Comment: ... it's a new project I got and just got it under subversion locally, ready to do initial import and I realized the target directory (in the project structure) is under svn too. I didn't tell intellij/svn to ignore that one hence the question. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: In that case you can simply 'revert' the target directory. It will then not be added to version control. You should probably set it to 'ignore' afterwards to prevent this from happening in the future.

Answer (score 28):

I suppose the best way is to remove svn configuration in the project settings:

File > Settings, then Version Control.
There should be Suversion item in the list. 
Try to remove this line with the "-" button on the right.

Hope this helps.

Comment: after that you can also remove the .svn folders without a problem

Comment: I'm so glad I found your answer!  IntelliJ found `.svn` folders in a library I was using and wouldn't stop pestering me about every file in it!

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer. I had a project based on git checkout locally, imported into IntelliJ. For some reason IntelliJ was enabling SVN for it. This let me remove the SVN binding and add git.

Answer (score 22):

File -> Settings -> Version Control -> select Project -> Click button(red)

[image]

Comment: For intellij on mac, it is Intellij IDEA -> Preferences -> Version Control

Comment: Jetbrains should really clean up the confusion and move project specific preferences to project settings instead of global preferences.